# Filenet - How to get the Property values in Workflow group

Tags: filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

I have 2 Filenet Workflows where the firstWF takes the userids and store it on document property as String separated by comma. What I want from my SecondWF is that it should take that userids and assign it to workflow group when secondWF launch. I think it could be possible if it would be any step except Launch step on SecondWF by converting String to array & then assign it to Workflow group but I am unsure how to do it at the Launch step of SecondWF.

Answer (score 0):

1. to create a STRING data field dfA in WF2 to store the comma-separated string.
2. to mapping property from document to workflow launch step (expose dfA) using entry template (or you can use CREATE function in WF 1).
3. on Launch step property page -> Assignments tab, use the Expression Builder to parse dfA and prefix each cell value with '@' and append to your WfGrp (participants array type) field.

Done.

Comment: I haven't tried what you have mentioned but on your #3 on Assignment tab it says "After Completion" means that whatever we do here it gonna execute after Launch step and display it on the next step..right? I need that list to be displayed at the Launch step.

Comment: There are two ways:
1) To create a small Wf which includes only one step to bridge WF 1 and WF 2. this TechWF will do the string convertion and CREATE WF 2 at the end of it. 

2) To create a customized Event action subscription (duplicate Workflow subscription) to do the enhancement, and this Event action will be used for creating the WF 2.